# How to simulate press key in Python/Opencv?

Tags: python, opencv, pycharm

I am creating an opencv project to play the game pong. To play the game, I have to Put in the keys up and down to the game. How do I do this?

[In this project](https://github.com/robintwhite/pong-ai), I found a way to for Key presses. He has a directory utils with the package. He imports it in play.py with the statement

> from utils.directkeys import PressKey, ReleaseKey

I copied the utils directory in my project folder, but when I type import utils.directkeys, I dont have access to it.

Can someone tell me a way how to presskey in python OR how I could access the package in my project?

Comment: Can you show us the exact error you are receiving when you try to import the module?

Comment: I get the error message: Can not find reference 'directkeys' in '__init__.py'

Answer (score 1):

You need to add a file called `__init__.py` inside the `utils` directory of your project to ensure that the directory is treated as a submodule. Given your current use case, it can just be a blank file.

However this file is no longer required as of Python 3.3. You are either using Python 2.7, or using a version of Python 3 that is below 3.3. The repo that you got this from is most likely using a newer version of Python which is why you are seeing this error.

Please consider using the most up to date version of Python for your development.